# Dojo: Uncaught ReferenceError: normal is not defined

Tags: dojo

Today we update our chrome version to Version 67.0.3396.62 (Official Build) (64-bit)

and we started getting this issue in our old dojo application. Anyone having the same issue?

[dojo css.js VM434:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: normal is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtvIe.png)

Answer (score 5):

You are probably hitting this bug: https://github.com/kriszyp/xstyle/issues/44#issuecomment-76512785

Fix: either update xstyle to newer version or apply the fix mentioned in the above link.